# Directed graph with million of nodes, most with only a few edges but a few with hundreds of thousands

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, directed-graph

Suppose a directed graph has a million nodes, most nodes have only a few edges, but a few nodes have hundreds of thousands of edges.

To represent this graph, I used an adjacency matrix but, as it turns out, its running time is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** and for adjacency matrix random access is not efficient.

How can I represent this graph in an efficient way that could solve both random access and works faster?

Comment: What kind of random access? What are you actually doing with this graph?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218322/what-is-better-adjacency-lists-or-adjacency-matrices-for-graph-problems-in-c

Answer (score 1):

use the adjacency list, [see a  description here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/)