# Difference between adjacency list and adjacency matrix

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I often see my tutor referencing to both **adjacency lists** and **adjacency matrix** in *Graph theory*
But I still don't understand the difference?
Any help please?

Comment: [This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/) might help you.

Comment: Related post - [What is better, adjacency lists or adjacency matrices for graph problems in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2218322/465053)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Adjacency list` shows which nodes are connected to which, in the following format:

```
2 3 4 5
1 4
1 5 4
1 2 5 3
1 3 4
```

This means node `1` is connected to nodes `2, 3, 4 and 5`, node `2` is connected to `1 and 4`, and so on.

The `adjacency matrix`, on the other hand, does it in the following matrix format:

```
01111
10010
10011
11101
10110
```

It shows that if the 1st node and 2nd node are connected, there is a `1` at the grid[1][2] position, and `0` if the 2 nodes aren't connected, or if they are the same nodes.
Hope this helps!