# Which Graph Algorithms prefer adjacency matrix and why?

Tags: data-structures, graph, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I heard that adjacency lists are used in most graph algorithms (but not all). I'm just wondering what algorithms prefer adjacency matrices and why?

So far I’ve found that Floyd Warshall uses adjacency matrices.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adjacency lists are generally faster than adjacency matrices in algorithms in which the key operation performed per node is “iterate over all the nodes adjacent to this node.” That can be done in time O(deg(v)) time for an adjacency list, where deg(v) is the degree of node v, while it takes time Θ(n) in an adjacency matrix. Similarly, adjacency lists make it fast to iterate over all of the edges in a graph - it takes time O(m + n) to do so, compared with time Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) for adjacency matrices.

Some of the most-commonly-used graph algorithms (BFS, DFS, Dijkstra’s algorithm, A* search, Kruskal’s algorithm, Prim’s algorithm, Bellman-Ford, Karger’s algorithm, etc.) require fast iteration over all edges or the edges incident to particular nodes, so they work best with adjacency lists.

You mentioned that Floyd-Warshall uses adjacency matrices. While Floyd-Warshall does maintain an internal matrix tracking shortest paths seen so far, it doesn’t actually require the original graph to be an adjacency matrix. The overall cost of the dynamic programming work is Θ(n<sup>3</sup>), which is bigger than the O(n<sup>2</sup>) cost of converting an adjacency list into an adjacency matrix or vice-versa.

There are only a few places where an adjacency matrix is faster than an adjacency list. Adjacency matrices take time O(1) to test whether a particular edge is present in the graph, which is faster than the O(deg(v)) cost of the corresponding operation on an adjacency list. Since the cost of converting an adjacency list to an adjacency matrix is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), the only cases where an adjacency matrix would outperform an adjacency list are in situations where (1) random access of the edges are required and (2) the total runtime of the algorithm is o(n<sup>2</sup>). I only know a few algorithms that do this. For example, there’s the [*celebrity-finding problem*](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos423/problem0-1.pdf) where you’re given a graph and are asked to find whether there’s a node with incoming edges from each node and outgoing edges to no nodes. This can be done in time O(n) using an adjacency matrix, faster than what can be done with an adjacency list.

(That being said, you could also use an adjacency list represented using [cuckoo hash tables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing) rather than regular lists and match the same runtime bounds as above, though with the cost of creating the adjacency list now only *expected* to be fast rather than actually worst-case efficient.)

The main reason I’ve found adjacency matrices to be useful is in thinking about graphs from a different perspective. For example, raising an adjacency matrix to the kth power makes a new matrix that counts the number of paths from one node to another using exactly k hops. This can be used to [count and find triangles in graphs faster than the naive algorithm](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Evirgi/cs267/lecture1.pdf), for example. Similarly, the [Four Russians algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Four_Russians) for computing transitive closures of graphs works by representing the graph as a matrix and using some clever techniques (treating blocks of bits as integers then used in a lookup table) to outperform the naive search.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you

Comment: What do m and n stand for?

Comment: @johan The convention in graph algorithms is that n denotes the number of nodes in the graph, and m denotes the number of edges.