# Boost DFS tutorial: from serial to parallel

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

So, I have implemented a *path overlap* on a graph with a custom-made A*, using `boost::graph`, but all developed from scratch.

What is a path overlap is simple. Given a graph of letters (`'A'-> 'C'`, ...), and a word HELLO, I need to find the *best overlapping* starting from `'H'` in the graph, ending in `'O'` (if it exists, or end when the path length is reached). The "best" refers to the way candidate nodes are chosen, simply exploring the letter that is nearer to the current one in the word. The graph weights are therefore dynamic, they depend on the input word. See the following example:

```
/*
 *    B          H
 *   / \        /
 *  A---D---F---G---I
 *   \ /\
 *    C  E
 *
 *  input:  A E I O U
 *  result: A D F G I
 */
```

What I've done is simple: using a DFS that tracks nodes and inserts them in a priority queue. Obviously, this isn't quite optimal: I'd very much like to use `boost::depth_first_search`.

My problem is simple: all the examples use a graph traversal with no initial node. The graph is *very* large, like 8M nodes minimum, hoping to get up to 100M nodes, on a cluster. So I am aiming to distribute the graph over a cluster with Parallel BGL.

What to you suggest?

Probably my from scratch approach isn't really the best one, it would be easier to use BGL, but although I succeeded in trying a very basic `astar_search`, I am failing to try a simple `depth_first_search`. I am unable to understand color maps and how I can set the destination node, so I will post my code, hoping someone will point me in the right direction.

Note again, I need to move the code, when it will work, to Parallel BGL.

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <list>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/astar_search.hpp>

// Funky
std::unordered_map<char, int> letters;
auto getletter = [](std::size_t i) -> char { return 'A' + i; };


typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, // V
                              boost::vecS, // E
                              boost::bidirectionalS,
                              boost::no_property,
                              int // Ignore weights for now
                              > graph;

typedef boost::graph_traits<graph>::edge_iterator edge_iterator;

// Used to end the A*-like search algorithm
struct end_astar { };

// Custom A* visitor
template <class Vertex>
class bestmatch_visitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor //public boost::default_astar_visitor
{
public:

    // Constructor
    bestmatch_visitor(Vertex goal) : destination_(goal) { };

    // ==============
    // == VERTICES ==
    // ==============

    template<class Graph>
    void initialize_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph &g)
    {
        std::cout << "init " << u << " " << getletter(u) << std::endl;
    }

    // Push a new vertex in the stack
    template<class Graph>
    void discover_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph &g)
    {
        std::cout << "discover " << u << " " << getletter(u) << std::endl;
    }

    // Pop a vertex and examine it
    template <class Graph>
    void examine_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g)
    {
        std::cout << ">>>>> examine " << u << " " << getletter(u) << std::endl;

        if (u == destination_) throw end_astar();
    }

    // Vertex examined, moving to the blacklist
    template <class Graph>
    void finish_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g)
    {
        std::cout << "vertex examined, closing " << u << " " << getletter(u) << std::endl;
    }

    // ===========
    // == EDGES ==
    // ===========

    // Examine out edges
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
    void examine_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g)
    {
        std::cout << "--> edge examine " << e << std::endl;
    }

    // Relax edge if distance from goal reduces
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
    void edge_relaxed(Edge e, const Graph& g)
    {
        std::cout << "--> edge relax " << e << std::endl;
    }

    // Distance from goal does not decrease: don't relax
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
    void edge_not_relaxed(Edge e, const Graph& g)
    {
        std::cout << "--> edge NOT relaxed " << e << std::endl;
    }

    // Ooops! Already checked this one
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
    void black_target(Edge e, const Graph& g)
    {
        std::cout << "--> BLACKLISTED " << e << std::endl;
    }


private:
    Vertex destination_;
};


int main()
{
    /*
     *    B          H
     *   / \        /
     *  A---D---F---G---I
     *   \ /\
     *    C  E
     *
     *  input:  A Z I M U T
     *  result: A C D F G I
     *
     *  nodes:  ABCDEFGHI
     *  codes:  012345678
     */

    for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'I'; i++) letters[i] = i - 'A';

    graph g;

    boost::add_edge(letters['A'], letters['B'], g);
    boost::add_edge(letters['A'], letters['C'], g);
    boost::add_edge(letters['A'], letters['D'], g);

    boost::add_edge(letters['B'], letters['D'], g);

    boost::add_edge(letters['C'], letters['D'], g);

    boost::add_edge(letters['D'], letters['E'], g);
    boost::add_edge(letters['D'], letters['F'], g);

    boost::add_edge(letters['F'], letters['G'], g);

    boost::add_edge(letters['G'], letters['H'], g);
    boost::add_edge(letters['G'], letters['I'], g);

    edge_iterator ei, ee;

    for (boost::tie(ei, ee) = boost::edges(g); ei != ee; ei++)
    {
        graph::edge_descriptor d = *ei;

        std::cout << getletter(boost::source(*ei, g)) << " -> " <<
        getletter(boost::target(*ei, g)) << "    " << std::endl; //<< g[d] << std::endl;
    }

    // Predecessors
    std::vector<graph::vertex_descriptor> p(boost::num_vertices(g));

    // Distances
    std::vector<graph::vertex_descriptor> d(boost::num_vertices(g));

    // Color: HOW?
    //typename boost::property_map<graph, boost::vertex_color_t>::type c;

    // Start and finish
    int start = letters['A'];
    int goal  = letters['I'];

    bestmatch_visitor<int> v(letters['A']);

    // Useless:
    boost::depth_first_search(g, boost::visitor(v));

    // HOW?
    //boost::depth_first_visit(g, letters['A'], boost::visitor(v), c);

}
```

Comment: I've received some books about Boost and BGL in particular. I don't see at a glance any answer for this, so if a Good Samaritan could help... :)

Comment: You can set the DFS start node with `boost::depth_first_search(g, visitor(v).root_vertex(vertex_desc));` I have a simple DFS example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867222/boost-minimum-spanning-tree-how-to-do-depth-first/22327218#22327218). As for parallel, I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you have a Bellman-Ford visitor defined, not a DFS visitor. Note that there is no parallel `bellman_ford_shortest_paths`, but there are several other shortest-paths algorithms available.
   https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/index.html
2. `boost::depth_first_search` can be given a starting vertex with `root_vertex`.
3. You shouldn't need to input a color map; if you use the `boost::vecS` storage type for your vertices, one will be provided for you. Otherwise, you can create a color map like this:

```
using Vert = boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor
using Map = std::unordered_map<Vert, boost::default_color_type, boost::hash<Vert>>;

Map stlColors;
auto boostColors = boost::make_assoc_property_map(stlColors);
```

5. The API for the parallel graph tools has changed, but the documentation has not been updated to reflect this. There are also unexpected behaviors in the parallel version of the algorithms that do not map back to the serial behavior.

   a. In parallel, you want `depth_first_visit` or `tsin_depth_first_visit`, not `depth_first_search`, which will start from different nodes on each process.

   b. You have to be really careful with distributed `property_map`s. Just reading from the map can cause MPI operations to fire off, which can cause `depth_first_visit` variants to lock up. To make matters worse, the lockups are nondeterministic due to the asynchronous model of the `mpi_process_group.` `breadth_first_search` has been a lot more robust in my experience. I haven't tested the shortest-paths algorithms, but since the issues appear to arise from the distributed `property_map`s, don't assume that just because it works on 8 processes, it won't freeze on 16...or freeze the fourth time you run it on 8 processes.

   c. There is a bug in the `mpi_process_group` parallel boost graph library associated with having zero nodes on some processes There's a fix here: https://github.com/boostorg/graph_parallel/issues/18