# A visitor to provide all vertex routes from root to each branch end

Tags: c++, boost, depth-first-search, boost-graph, visitor-pattern

I have found this [general example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14127) for building a visitor for a depth first search, but I'm unsure of how to build a visitor for my intent.

I have an unweighted tree.  I want to find all shortest routes from a root to each branch end, a vertex with only one edge connecting to the rest of the graph.

For example, in this graph (**borrowed from elsewhere**)

[image]

if `12` were the root, the branch ends would be `4`, `1`, `9`, `10`, and `7`.  The first route would contain `12`, `11`, `5`, `2`, `4`.  The second route would contain `12`, `11`, `5`, `2`, `1`.  And so on.

In the example provided

```
class MyVisitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor
{
public:
  void discover_vertex(MyVertex v, const MyGraph& g) const
  {
    cerr << v << endl;
    return;
  }
};
```

I do no see a way to determine which route `discover_vertex` is currently searching.

How can my intent be implemented?

Comment: Sorry, I have read the question more carefully and now I don't understand it at all. Obviously you cannot change the boost visitor interface. Your visitor object should probably keep track of the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "track" which "route" vertex is currently being explored, you can use code similar to "predecessor_recorder" in your visitor.

Details on predefined predecessor_recorder can be found here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/predecessor_recorder.html.

In fact, you probably would better of with dijkstra_shortest_paths. That algorithm reports a predecessor map for you. You can call Dijkstra and afterwards simply go over predecessor map and generate your paths of interest for vertices of interest.

Comment: Thank you for that hidden nugget.  I think I'm missing something fundamental because I can't seem to reconstruct the paths from the output of these functions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html  I've avoided Dijkstra because I'm using bundled properties and can't figure out how to apply the weights.  The weights are all equal in my case.

Comment: The algorithms DFS and BFS do not store the predecessor map; that is why you cannot extract it from their output. You can work around that using predecessor_recorder, which will register the predecessors.

Comment: To use Dijkstra with all edge weights equal to 1, you pass 'boost::dummy_property_map(1)' as edge-weight map to Dijkstra.